# Camera app crashing on Nexus i9250 Android 4.2.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean, camera

I just bought a i9250 Nexus, and the system proposed to upgrade to newer version 4.2.1 (it is not a rooted phone. It is an unblocked UK phone)

I played with the new phone and after a couple of days I did upgrade it.

Now the camera is not working. When I try to use the camera, it calls the application and before I can see any image from camera, it says "Unfortunately the GALLERY has stopped"

How can I downgrade to previous version? (The phone is not rooted)

Or, does anybody knows how to fix it? or anything that I can try to bring the camera back to action?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data of the camera or gallery apps?

Answer (score 0):

An update to 4.2.2 should fix the bugs. My Galaxy Nexus has been running a lot more stable since the update.
You should be able to find the update in 
Settings>>About Phone>>System Updates.